# Wiremock stub get http status 503

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

H1,

I have service to check URL, I would like to test it with integration test using Wiremock. For that I have a application-integration.yml containing a map of url and integration test. I would like to create a stub for these URL to have an http 200 or 404. When launch my test all URL get an http 503, it's look like my stub not working.

Service :

```
 package com.omb;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CheckUrlService {

     private final MyProperties properties;
     

    public void check() {


        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
        Map<String, String> uris = properties.getUris();
        customThreadPool.submit(() -> uris.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(key -> {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uris.get(key));
                HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                huc.setConnectTimeout(properties.getConnectTimeout());
                huc.setReadTimeout(properties.getReadTimeout());
                int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
                if (!HttpStatus.OK.equals(responseCode)) {
                    log.error("service unreachable {} on url {} with error : {}", key, uris.get(key), responseCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("service unreachable {} on url {} with error : {}", key, uris.get(key), e.getMessage());
            }
        }));
        customThreadPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

TEST

```
package com.omb;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
public class ExternalCallMonitoringServiceIT {

    @Inject
    protected WireMockServer wireMock;
    @Inject
    protected CheckUrlService service;
    protected MemoryAppender memoryAppender;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(CheckUrlService.class);
        memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
        memoryAppender.setContext((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory());
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.addAppender(memoryAppender);
        memoryAppender.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void resetWireMocks() {
        wireMock.resetAll();
    }

    @Test
    void given_reachable_url_should_not_log_error() throws IOException {
        wireMock.stubFor(WireMock.any(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("http://url-to-check")).willReturn(WireMock.ok()));
        service.checkExternalCall();
        Awaitility.waitAtMost(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).untilAsserted(() -> Assertions.assertEquals(2, memoryAppender.list.size()));
    }

    @Test
    void given_unreachable_url_should_log_error() throws IOException {
        wireMock.givenThat(WireMock.get("http://url-to-check").willReturn(WireMock.notFound()));
        service.checkExternalCall();
        Awaitility.waitAtMost(Duration.ofMillis(500)).untilAsserted(() -> Assertions.assertEquals(3, memoryAppender.list.size()));
        Awaitility.waitAtMost(Duration.ofMillis(500)).untilAsserted(() -> Assertions.assertEquals(1, memoryAppender.search(
            "service unreachable service-to-check on url http://url-to-check with error : 404", Level.ERROR).size()));
    }

}
```

application-integration.yml

```
my-project:
  uris:
    service-to-check: http://url-to-check
```

Comment: Where do you set your urls in the tests? Because in this configuration wiremock will use a random port and your service urls will have to be adjusted. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @MichałKrzywański I added the application-integration.yml